# How to put a loading gif image, while my app is doing a operation?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to put a loading gif image, while my app is getting data from the database, I have to put a image of "Loading" in my view, I've tried with UIImageView and with the hidden property, but it doesnt show the image. is there a way to put the image.

Comment: We can assume (if the gif is animated) that you use UIImageView's `animationImages` property instead of just putting a gif into the UIImageView? You can't show animated GIFs directly in UIImageView

Answer (score 6):

Check out [SVProgressHUD](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/svprogresshud). You can easily show a loading screen with a line like:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
```

and dismiss it with `[SVProgressHUD dismiss];`
[image]

Comment: `showInView::` is depreciated and has been removed.  The net method in this case would be `showWithStatus:`.  I edited your answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1):

Do you do the DB operation by means of an [asynchronous block](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1)? iOS is likely to not update the UI, if your **operation is synchronous**.

To perform an asynchronous operation, you should use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) like this:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        ... code here will be executed asynchronously ---

});
```

When the asynchronous block finished, some code needs to drive the UI one step further.

Even if on a single core device, Apple proposes to use asynchronous blocks.

Comment: yes is synchronous. So if I use a Run-loop the UI gets update?